# What is the coefficient of $x^4y^3z^3$ in the expansion of $(5x+1y+5z)^{10}$?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> What is the coefficient of $x^4y^3z^3$ in the expansion of $(5x+1y+5z)^{10}$?

So, would I start by using the binomial or multinomial theorem? Not entirely sure where to start here?

Comment: The coefficient of $a^4b^3c^3$ in the expansion of $(a+b+c)^{10}$ is $\frac{10!}{4!\,3!\,3!}=4200$, according to the multinomial theorem.

Comment: @vvv123: The multinomial theorem is the quickest way, but you could certainly apply the binomial theorem twice to get the same result, by grouping.

Comment: See [multinomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) and [Pascal's pyramid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal's_pyramid).

Answer (score 4):

Write the product of ten copies of $(5x+1y+5z)$, and count the choices: you pick $4$ times an $x$ among the factors, $3$ times an $y$ in the remaining factors, and in the remaining $3$ times a $z$, hence the number of possibilities is:

$${10 \choose 4,3,3}={10\choose4}{10-4\choose3}{10-4-3\choose3}=210\cdot20\cdot1=4200$$

Each of these $4200$ possibilities contributes a factor $5^4\cdot1^3\cdot5^3$, hence the coefficient you are looking for is

$$4200\cdot5^4\cdot1^3\cdot5^3=328125000$$